# How can I set Orientation Fixed for all activities

Tags: android, layout, orientation

Android Layout. How can I set Orientation Fixed for all activities in application Tag of AndroidMainfest.xml ?
I don't want to set orientation for each activity individually.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The [GoogleIO](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/) app has a ActivityHelper class. It has a static method called `initialize()` which handles a lot things that happen for every Activity. Then it is just 1 line of code in the `onCreate()` method that you need to remember, that could handle setting that value and several others that are necessary for each activity.

**Edit:** No importing or anything like that. Create a class called ActivityHelper

```
public class ActivityHelper {
    public static void initialize(Activity activity) {
        //Do all sorts of common task for your activities here including:

        activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    }
}
```

Then in all of your activies onCreate() method call `ActivityHelper.initialize()`
If you are planning on developing for tables as well you may want to consider using:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR);
```

I wrote more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605986/android-natural-sensor-orientation-help)

**Edit:** Sorry... you need to pass the the Activity. see the code above

Comment: Thanks bytebender, Can you please tell me how can I use ActivityHelper class in my project ? any example would be appreciable. I followed your link, but still confused.

Comment: Give me a bit... I will write out some code later tonight and post it here.

Comment: Many thanks for feedback, I just wana know, In my project, what files or jar i have to import, and how will I call that static methods. waiting for your kind response.

Comment: Thanks for your details, just one thing more please. In ActivityHelper Class on setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE); I a getting a compilation error, "The method setRequestedOrientation(int) is undefined for the type ActivityHelper" Can you tell me what is solution to resolve this red line.

Comment: Hmm, its works now, thanks for your support and co-operation.

Comment: What if I use android.app.Activity, android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity, android.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity in one application.  I don't know their difference but I realized I am using them all. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Eugene you are much more likely to get an answer to your question if you move it out of the comments and create a new Stack question...

Comment: This solution is far from perfect, because, [as stated in documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setRequestedOrientation(int)), setRequestedOrientation may cause the activity to be restarted, which among other things, affects animations between the screens.

Comment: @bytebender, Great Answer buddy. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer, and anything suggesting `setRequestedOrientation`, is far from perfect, because, [as stated in documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setRequestedOrientation(int)), **calling `setRequestedOrientation` at runtime may cause the activity to be restarted, which among other things, affects animations between the screens.**

If possible, the best is to set the desired orientation in `AndroidManifest.xml`.
But since it's error prone to rely on each developer to remember to modify the manifest when adding a new activity, it can be done at build time, by editing AndroidManifest file during the build.

There are some caveats to editing AndroidManifest this way that you need to be aware of though:

- If you have some `<activity-alias>` entries in the output manifest, you should match `<activity(?!-)` instead of `<activity` to avoid modifying those (and use `replaceAll`, which matches regex, instead of `replace`, which matches string)
- Be careful to not match the activities that are out of your control. See [facebook + android : Only fullscreen opaque activities can request orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47093127)

My requirement was to **update all activities to have fixed orientation, but only in release builds**. I achieved it with a bit of code in `build.gradle` which does simple string replacement in AndroidManifest (assuming that *none* of the activities has orientation specified already):

Android Studio 3.0 compatible solution example (touching only activities that match `com.mycompany.*`):

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all { output ->
        if (output.name == "release") {
            output.processManifest.doLast {
                String manifestPath = "$manifestOutputDirectory/AndroidManifest.xml"
                def manifestContent = file(manifestPath).getText('UTF-8')
                // replacing whitespaces and newlines between `<activity>` and `android:name`, to facilitate the next step
                manifestContent = manifestContent.replaceAll("<activity\\s+\\R\\s+", "<activity ")
                // we leverage here that all activities have android:name as the first property in the XML
                manifestContent = manifestContent.replace(
                        "<activity android:name=\"com.mycompany.",
                        "<activity android:screenOrientation=\"userPortrait\" android:name=\"com.mycompany.")
                file(manifestPath).write(manifestContent, 'UTF-8')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Android Studio 2.3 compatible solution example (matching all activities, but not matching `<activity-alias>` entries):

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        if (output.name == "release") {
            output.processManifest.doLast {
                def manifestOutFile = output.processManifest.manifestOutputFile
                def newFileContents = manifestOutFile.getText('UTF-8')
                        .replaceAll(/<activity(?!-)/, "<activity android:screenOrientation=\"userPortrait\" ")
                manifestOutFile.write(newFileContents, 'UTF-8')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I used `userPortrait` instead of `portrait` as I prefer to give the user more flexibility.

The above works out of the box if you just have variants (debug, release). If you additionally have flavors, you might need to tweak it a bit.

You might want to remove `if (output.name == "release")` depending on your needs.

Answer (score 2):

**If you write your project with generics.**

And you have something like "BaseActivity" than inside **onCreate** it you can write code like that:

**For Example:**
BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity, later you use YourActivity extends 
BaseActivity

**Portrait**

```
this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

**Landscape**

```
this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

Comment: And where are generics?

Comment: @CoolMind i mean when you write your project with generics, you have to create them by yourself. TLDR you create class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity or something ,and later in all your activites you extend by your baseActivity.
*and in the base activity on create you write those lines*

Comment: Then you should say: "If you extend your activity from BaseActivity". Your idea is good.

Answer (score 0):

(Monodroid/C# code)

You can create an abstract base class

```
public abstract class ActBase : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        RequestedOrientation = clsUtilidades.GetScreenOrientation();
    }
 }
```

Then all your activities must inherit this class instead *Activity*

Somehting like

```
[Activity(Label = "Orders", ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.Keyboard | ConfigChanges.Mcc | ConfigChanges.Mnc)]
public class ActOrders : ActBase
{
  ....
```

This way avoids call the *ActivityHelper* in your events

Answer (score 0):

I got the best solution. You don't have to pass any activity as parameter and stuff.

Here's what you have to do.

Create a class and extend your application like this. 
Implement onActivityCreated and onActivityStarted and add the code that sets the orientation to whichever you want.

```
public class OldApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // register to be informed of activities starting up
        registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new ActivityLifecycleCallbacks() {

            @Override
            public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {
                activity.setRequestedOrientation(
                        ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle bundle) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity,
                                          Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              activity.setRequestedOrientation(
                        ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
              }
        });
    }
}
```

After this, add the following in your Manifest file inside the `<application block>`:

```
android:name=".OldApp"
```

End result will be like this:

```
<application
    android:name=".OldApp"
    ...other values... >
    <activity
        android:name=".SomeActivity"></activity>
</application>
```