# Android natural sensor orientation help

Tags: android, orientation, android-sensors

I am trying to accomplish Reto Meier's recommended way for keeping the screen orientation from changing. The slides from his talk during Google IO (see #23) can be found in *[Android Protips: Where to Download the Slides and Code Snippets](http://blog.radioactiveyak.com/2011/05/android-protips-where-to-download.html)*.

I have stepped through the code and it setting the values, but the screen orientation still changes. FYI, I register this listener in the Application.

Here is my code:

```
final SensorManager sm = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    sm.registerListener(
        new SensorEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
                if (sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION) {
                    final WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getApplicationContext()
                            .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
                    final Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();

                    int x = SensorManager.AXIS_X;
                    int y = SensorManager.AXIS_Y;

                    switch (display.getRotation()) {
                    case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                        x = SensorManager.AXIS_Y;
                        y = SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_X;

                        break;
                    case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                        y = SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_Y;

                        break;
                    case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                        x = SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_Y;
                        y = SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_X;

                        break;
                    case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                    default:
                        break;
                    }

                    SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(sensorEvent.values, x, y, new float[] {});
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

            }
        }, sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION),
        SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All 30+ lines of code that currently are not working can be replaced with some XML values in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

We have all seen

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" ></activity>
```

and we all know that doesn't work well with tablets that have a default orientation of landscape. But how many of you have seen this?

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity" android:screenOrientation="nosensor" ></activity>
```

Basically it makes it so that the device's orientation doesn't respond to the sensor. So if your default is landscape or portrait it won't change. I have tested it on my [Droid X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorola_Droid_X) and on a [Xoom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorola_Xoom) and it works like I would have expected it to.

I hope this helps others.

Comment: Just keep in mind that orientation still changes for devices with hardware keyboard on open/close.

Comment: Sadly, tablets with default landscape orientation are enough to give you a bunch of negative votes (one star) after having spend a lot of time and efforts in developing an application. I have experienced this!

Comment: Very good solution. Works both with my tablet and my smartphone.

Comment: So are you saying `android:screenOrientation="nosensor"` doesn't work for the 7" tablet?