# Android. Lock orientation of screen for all Activities

Tags: android, android-manifest, screen-orientation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I set Orientation Fixed for all activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582761/how-can-i-set-orientation-fixed-for-all-activities)

I would like to lock my screen orientation for my app. I mean that all Activities must have the same `landscape` orientation. I don't want to add  `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` in the manifest for all activities. Is there any other way? thanks 
Regards

Comment: The thing which you want is being fulfilled by **screenOrientation** then why do you want any other Option... :|

Comment: Can you please explain why you don't want it in  manifest ?

Comment: Why not you lock it at runtime? Please elaborate exactly what you want.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/6582761/1321873

Comment: I want some code or part of code , that I must to add in the manifest , but I don't want to add some code for all activities , also I want to know is there any normal way , for example my app has 40 different activities and it's not normal to add some code for all these activities 40 times:)

Comment: Dear Rajesh I need some code for manifest , tell the truth I'm new in android , and I think it's not normal if there not any way to do this without any class helper , or add row of code for all activities. I think it Should have some easy way

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You have two options for achieving the result.

- You can specify per activity base orientation requirement in manifest file. You can select here what orientation you want to support for which activity.

e.g.

```
<activity
    android:name=".Some_Act"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
</activity>
```

- You can create a base activity and specify the orientation in that activity. Later you can inherit that activity in other activities of your application. You can choose suitable base class to get the desired behavior.

Comment: What you would insert into the base activity: `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);`

Comment: second one - is bad option.
cos if phone in landscape orientation - it will start landscape firs, and than will be recreated! if you have some methods in onCreate - it will run twice.
so my advise - use first method (manifest one)

Comment: If you want to avoid the problem explained in the comment above, check my answer in the linked question that allows locking orientation for all activities at build time: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46935264/245966

Answer (score 1):

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

Add the above lines in your app's manifest for all the activities .

Comment: dont read the question @ answer it

Comment: so u mean the above code wil not work? @boulder

Comment: Dear Goofy I it's not a good way if my app has 40 different activities , but thanks for attention :)