# Android , Set orientation for entire app in java (include fragments)

Tags: android, fragment, orientation

I'm checking the size of the device and if it's not tablet I'll set orientation to portrait so I can't set orientation at `Manifest`. I'm checking the size and orientation at each `Activity` like this:

```
if(Services.isMobile()){
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}
```

But it has two problems `1.`I have to do like so an all activities (and there is a lot of them)
`2.`It doesn't work for `Fragments`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12860087/3819810

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable orientation change in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512045/how-to-disable-orientation-change-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

You should add `android:screenOrientation` attribute to `<activity>` declaration in your manifest. For more details on what values the attribute accepts, see [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen)

Answer (score 0):

You must declare it in the manifest file of every activity like 
 android:screenOrientation="portrait"

Or you can create a base class and make it abstract
[StackOverflow portrait mode only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6745797/how-to-set-entire-application-in-portrait-mode-only)

Answer (score 0):

You can perform that programmatically :

You should test in all activities, or create a class and implement it in every activities.

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Use it in FragmentActivity & it will work on fragments. Just be sure to have a correct layout