# Set orientation fixed for all activities

Tags: android, orientation, manifest

I know there are two ways to set an `Activity`'s orientation to landscape, either programmatically

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

or in the Manifest:

```
android:orientation="landscape"
```

Currently, I use the first one in a superclass, because I have many (child) activities that I all want to be always in landscape. However, this make 
`onCreate` being called twice, which leads to other issues. When using the Manifest-route, I have to apply it to all activities separately, which will undoubtedly lead to one being missed out in the future (not to mention all the code copying).

Is there a way to apply `android:orientation="landscape"` to all activities in my app?

Comment: yeah you can do this by adding in manifest.

Comment: have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582761/how-can-i-set-orientation-fixed-for-all-activities

Comment: @johnrao07 That's how it is working now (by using a superclass); this leads to `onCreate` being called twice though.

Comment: What problem you are facing while setting these to your base activity

Comment: Problem with setting it to all: 1) difficult to change the value 2) impossible to have different value for different build variants

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the manifest, set this for all your activities:

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity"
android:configChanges="orientation"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

Let me explain:

With android:configChanges="orientation" you tell Android that you will be responsible of the changes of orientation.
android:screenOrientation="portrait" you set the default orientation mode.

Comment: I understand that, but this way I have to do it for each activity separately, which I don't want, because I will eventually forget one.

Comment: you will have to add this in each activity as of now android doesnt provide any feature like that..

Answer (score 2):

Or you can try make "superclass" for all activities and extends from "superclass".

```
public abstract class SuperActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

Comment: Read the question. That is what I have now.

Answer (score 0):

OnCreate **will be** called when an activity is created. When you setting in code

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

Activity recreates itself, so you can't really stop that. (maybe you can, try it, when you get a solution try posting..)

You gotta handle your stuff that way

**Possible Solutions**

> android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
>       in manifiest in  tag

**OR**

> Add it directly in your manifest the orientation property

Comment: Read the question. That is what I posted. I was looking for a way to apply that argument to all activities in the manifest at once.

Answer (score 0):

I set screen orientation for all activities in my application class.

```
import android.app.Application
import android.os.Bundle
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo

class MyApplication : Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        setListenerToCheckActivitySettings()
    }

    private fun setListenerToCheckActivitySettings() {

        registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(object : ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {
            override fun onActivityCreated(activity: Activity, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

                activity.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
            }

            override fun onActivityStarted(activity: Activity) {}
            override fun onActivityResumed(activity: Activity) {}
            override fun onActivitySaveInstanceState(activity: Activity, outState: Bundle?) {}
            override fun onActivityPaused(activity: Activity) {}
            override fun onActivityStopped(activity: Activity) {}
            override fun onActivityDestroyed(activity: Activity) {}
        })
    }
}
```