# facebook + android : Only fullscreen opaque activities can request orientation

Tags: android, facebook, android-8.0-oreo

Facebook SDK version **4.27.0**

Android OS version **8.0**

App crashes with exception, this is the trace log I have found over Crashlytics:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xxx.yyy/com.facebook.FacebookActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only fullscreen opaque activities can request orientation
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2822)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2897)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1598)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:251)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6563)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only fullscreen opaque activities can request orientation
       at android.app.Activity.onCreate(Activity.java:986)
       at android.support.v4.app.SupportActivity.onCreate(SupportActivity.java:66)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:285)
       at com.facebook.FacebookActivity.onCreate(FacebookActivity.java:62)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2775)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2897)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1598)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:251)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6563)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Can anyone help me with this ?

**PS:**
In Android Source, after looking at this line number 987, it seems that this line is the culprit.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/java/android/app/Activity.java#1002

Also, in my manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Removing this attribute:

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

from `FacebookActivity` tag, may solve the problem.

Comment: I haven't added above line in `FacebookActivity` but if `<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">trus</item>` is present in your style then you have to remove that and its worked

Answer (score 3):

From the latest fb integration guide, we don't need to specify either theme or orientation that is causing crash on android 8.0 . So we should use latest fb sdk with their new settings:

```
<activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
    android:configChanges=
            "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
    android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/#manifest

Answer (score 2):

When i removed this `<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>` from style  problem was solved.

Comment: **Removing** `<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>` from my style that inherits from `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`  also worked for me.

Comment: I fixed this issue on my app ! thanx !

Comment: @Rafa0809 have you found any solution without removing `<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>` and with `android:screenOrientation="portrait"`

Answer (score 0):

remove this line from your style menu

```
  <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Changed

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"></style>`
```

to

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.TranslucentDecor"></style>
```

then remove

```
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Android O and later this error happens when you set

```
 android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

This code is written in the AndroidManifest file:

```
<activity
android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"     android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"></activity>
```

Remove this from `manifest` file

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

and add below code to activity in oncreate before `setContentView` :

```
 setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

This will fix `illegalStateException` issue/

Comment: your answer is the same as **the best answer**

Comment: Danish Hassan has given reason for the issue and also the solution for it. He has explained the solution in right order.

Answer (score 0):

In the [Facebook Developer documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/#manifest) :

> If you use version 5.15 or later of the Facebook SDK for Android, you
> don't need to to add an activity or intent filter for Chrome Custom
> Tabs. This functionality is included in the SDK.

The problem is caused by :

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

and the presence of :

```
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
```

So if you remove this declaration from your Manifest, it should works:

```
<activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation" android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait" android:label="@string/app_name"/>
    
<activity android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity" android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait" android:exported="true">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_scheme" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```